# Can i get name of fields from API with automatic function React-Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

**I have json api:**
I know how to get record value :

something like this : `json.result.firstname = steve`

But i don't know how to get fields by  automatic function  (if i don't know fields  name) I want to get all fields with out parameter or index

```
{
    success: true,
    result: [
                {
                    salutationtype: "Mr.",
                    firstname: "Steve",
                    address: "",
                    contact_no: "CON14",
                    lastname: "Mart",
                    mobile: "05-3376147-3",
                    title: "",
                    fax: "",
                }
    ]
}
```

I need this output :

> > > > [label] salutationtype : Mr. <<<<< [input]
> > > >
> > > > [label] firstname : Steve <<<<< [input]
> > > >
> > > > [label] address : '   ' <<<<< [input] **** it's null
> > > >
> > > > [label] contact_no : CON14 <<<<< [input]
> > > >
> > > > [label] lastname : mart <<<<< [input]
> > > >
> > > > [label] mobile : 05-3376147-3 <<<<< [input]
> > > >
> > > > [label] title : '    ' <<<<< [input] **** it's null
> > > >
> > > > [label] fax : '    ' <<<<< [input] **** it's null

blah blah ~

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for in`, to display the fields dynamically.

```
const obj = json.result;
for (field in obj) {
  console.log(field + ' : ' + obj[field])
}
```